# Different density-functions in different books for Exp(a), why?

Tags: density-function, exponential-distribution

This is more of a theoretical question, that I hope someone is willing to explain to me.
I have noticed that the density function for the exponential distribution looks different in two of my books.
For Exp(a), why are these two expressions the same (?)?

$$
f_X(x)=ae^{-ax}  \quad\text{and}\quad     f_X(x)=\frac{1}{a}e^{-x/a}
$$

Comment: In the equation on the left, $a$ represents a "rate" and in the equation on the right, $a$ represents and "expected duration". This is really well explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They aren't the same. They are two different commonly used parameterizations of the exponential distribution. One uses the mean as the parameter, and the other uses the rate, which is 1/mean.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution), especially [the section on "Alternative Parameterization"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Alternative_parameterization) gives some background.

You simply need to be careful which parameterization you (and your software) are using.